# My code printing blank space instead of the input I have given

Tags: c

I have the code below and it is supposed to print the names I have given but instead it prints blank spaces.

I might've made a mistake with data type's because I was printing integers but not names. I couldn't figure it out.

Here's the full code but I think the main problem is at printStack function.

Edit: I've changed everything to english sorry for the confusion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 25

char stack[SIZE];
int top=-1;

int isFull(){
    if (top>=SIZE-1){
        return 1;
    }
        return 0;    
}

struct n{
    n * next;
    char data;
};

typedef n node;

void printStack(char person){
    printf("Entered persons: \n");
    for(int i=0;i<=top;i++)
        printf("%c\n",stack[person]);
    printf("\n");
}

void push(node * root, char person){
    if(root == NULL || isFull()){
        root = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        root -> data = person;
        root -> next = NULL;
        stack[++top]=person;
    }
    node * iter = root;
    while(iter->next !=NULL || isFull()){
        iter = iter -> next;
        stack[++top]=person;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int pick;
    char person;
    node * s=NULL;
    while (1){
       
       printf("1 - Add person\n");
       printf("2 - Show persons\n");
       printf("3 - Exit\n");
       
       scanf("%d",&pick);
       switch (pick){
            case 1: 
                printf ("Person name:  ");
                scanf("%s",&person);
                push(s, person);
                break;
            case 2:
                printStack(person);
                break;
            case 3:
                exit(0);
                break;
       }
                    
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```yolcu``` is of type ```char```. You're using ```%s``` to print it, and that too with ```&```.

Comment: You're passing the ```address-of``` ```yulco```, but not using the ```object of``` ```*``` operator in the called function.

Comment: @Emir, try `scanf("%s",&yolcu);` --> `scanf(" %c",&yolcu);`  (note the space and `c`)

Comment: The for loop will never execute. The condition ```i <= top``` will never be true as ```top = -1```, and ```i = 0```.

Comment: The `struct` doesn't compile for me.  It should be `struct n *next`.

Comment: You should translate your prompts to English.  At least I can't figure out what this should do.

Comment: I answered your question in the title below, if you want to store strings then you have to change your node to store a `char *`.  You need to modify push to take a `char *` and you probably want to use `strdup()` to make the copy of the string.  It's a different question, though, so if you need more help create a new question.

Comment: You also have an issue with push / allocation.  If you grow the stack then there is no such thing as full (other than malloc failing).  And if it's fixed size then you want to generate an error when you are full instead of adding more.  As you pass in `node *root` the value of root will not be updated (you need to do **root for that).

Comment: What kind of hybrid code is this? One part of it is a finite stack in parallel with a linked list... The simpler stack is used for output, but input is stored in both forms... It's little wonder there's confusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printStack()` iterates over stack but in the `printf()` call you print `stack[yolcu]` so the same thing `top + 1` times.  I think you mean to print `stack[i]`.  There is a logic error between 1 and later elements (first element top is 1 after 2nd element top is 3).  I suggest you use the normal c range [0; top[ where top is now size instead of a (possible invalid) index so initialize is to 0 instead of -1.  Iterate i<top.  Full if `top >= BOYUT`.  You want to use `scanf(" %c", ..)` to ignore the newline from previous prompt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BOYUT 25

char stack[BOYUT];
int top=0;

int isFull(){
    return top >= BOYUT;
}

typedef struct node {
    struct node *next;
    char data;
} node;

void printStack(){
    printf("Girilen yolcular: \n");
    for(int i=0;i<top;i++)
        printf("%i: %c\n",i, stack[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void push(node * root, char yolcu){
    if(root == NULL || isFull()){
        root = malloc(sizeof(node));
        root -> data = yolcu;
        root -> next = NULL;
        stack[top++]=yolcu;
    }
    node * iter = root;
    while(iter->next !=NULL || isFull()){
        iter = iter -> next;
        stack[top++]=yolcu;
    }
}

int main() {
    int secim;
    char yolcu;
    node *s=NULL;
    while (1){
        printf("1 - Yolcu Ekleme\n");
        printf("2 - Yolculari Goster\n");
        printf("3 - Cikis\n");
        scanf("%d",&secim);
        switch (secim){
            case 1:
                printf ("Yolcu Adi: ");
                scanf(" %c",&yolcu);
                push(s, yolcu);
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printStack();
                break;
            case 3:
                return 0;
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

and example session:

```
1 - Yolcu Ekleme
2 - Yolculari Goster
3 - Cikis
1
Yolcu Adi: a

1 - Yolcu Ekleme
2 - Yolculari Goster
3 - Cikis
1
Yolcu Adi: b

1 - Yolcu Ekleme
2 - Yolculari Goster
3 - Cikis
2
Girilen yolcular: 
0: a
1: b

1 - Yolcu Ekleme
2 - Yolculari Goster
3 - Cikis
```